# MYSQL - Cannot update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

[db-fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7gXiLbMrCZpFwknCLa4Pdg/4)

**SCHEMA QUERY**

```
-- GRAPH INFO TABLE--------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE GRAPH
(
    graph_id         CHAR(32)       NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
    name             VARCHAR(1024)  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO GRAPH set graph_id = MD5('graph1'),
                      name = 'graph1';
                               
INSERT INTO GRAPH set graph_id = MD5('graph2'),
                      name = 'graph2';
                      
INSERT INTO GRAPH set graph_id = MD5('graph3'),
                      name = 'graph3';
                      
-- FIELD INFO TABLE--------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE FIELD_TEST
(
    field_id    CHAR(50)        NOT NULL   PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR(500)    NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO FIELD_TEST set field_id = MD5('field1'),
                           name = 'field1';
                               
INSERT INTO FIELD_TEST set field_id = MD5('field2'),
                           name = 'field2';
                      
INSERT INTO FIELD_TEST set field_id = MD5('field3'),
                           name = 'field3';
                           
-- GRAPH FIELD RELATION TABLE-----------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST
(
    field_id    CHAR(32)                                   NOT NULL,
    graph_id    CHAR(32)                                   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (graph_id, field_id),
    CONSTRAINT GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST_FIELD_field_id_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (field_id) REFERENCES FIELD_TEST (field_id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST_GRAPH_STORAGE_graph_id_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (graph_id) REFERENCES GRAPH (graph_id)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST set field_id = MD5('field1'),
                                      graph_id = MD5('graph1');
                                      
INSERT INTO GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST set field_id = MD5('field2'),
                                      graph_id = MD5('graph2');     
                                      
INSERT INTO GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST set field_id = MD5('field3'),
                                      graph_id = MD5('graph3');
```

**UPDATE QUERY**

```
UPDATE FIELD_TEST
SET name     = 'new field1',
    field_id = MD5('new field1')
WHERE field_id = MD5('field1');
```

**ERROR**

```
Query Error: Error: ER_ROW_IS_REFERENCED_2: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST`, CONSTRAINT `GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST_FIELD_field_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`field_id`) REFERENCES `FIELD_TEST` (`field_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

If I change the ID of FIELD_TEST,

To change the GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST ID referring to the ID of FIELD_TEST,

I set it as cascade in GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST.

However, it fails due to the following error.

If I change the ID of GRAPH, it works normally,

but it doesn't work properly only if the ID of FIELD_TEST is changed.

May I know the reason for the error?

Comment: When showing the schema, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  That will include all indexes, the engine, and all foreign keys.  That will help us diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a Foreign Key is to *guarantee* that a corresponding values exists in another table.
A simplistic example would be that an OrderLine record cannot exist without a matching OrderHeader record.

```
select * from OrderHeader ; 

+---------------+------------+
| order_id (pk) | order_date | ... 
+---------------+------------+
|        123456 | 2021/11/03 | 
+---------------+------------+

select * from OrderLine ; 

+---------------+-----------+----------+
| order_id (fk) | stock_num | quantity | ... 
+---------------+-----------+----------+
|        123456 |    234567 |        1 | 
+---------------+-----------+----------+
```

So, with this Data and a Foreign Key constraint between the two tables on order_id, you *cannot* change the OrderHeader record's order_id, because that would leave the OrderLine record "orphaned" (*even if* you intended to update the OrderLine records to match, not that you should **ever** change record id's, but that's another story).
The Foreign Key actively *prevents* you from doing this.

You're seeing the same with your Tables & Data.

The Foreign Key from GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST to FIELD_TEST (on field) is preventing you from changing the field column in FIELD_TEST for *exactly* this reason.

To make this change, you must *insert* a new record into FIELD_TEST with the new Primary Key value, *update* the Foreign Key values in GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST to match this new value and then *delete* [the record with] the old primary key from FIELD_TEST, something like this:

```
insert into FIELD_TEST 
select (new_id), ... 
from FIELD_TEST 
where field = (old_id) ; 

update GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST 
set field = (new_id) 
where field = (old_id) ; 

delete from FIELD_TEST 
where field = (old_id) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

The field_id in your FIELD_TEST table is a CHAR(50), but in your GRAPH_FIELD_INFO_TEST table it's a CHAR(32).